# How to resolve arm code with if statement

Tags: c++, arm, embedded

I have 2 buttons connected to 5 volts on 1 end and to D4 and D2 in stm32F401RE board. I want to drive 2 digital outputs ,D7 and D0, on some LEDs that are on series with a resistance respectively ending to ground. An extra feature was to light a board LED for a specific time which is why I have written the while scantimes part.

I have written the code but I get an error to put ; after 10 in the if statement,even after I put it, it wont fix/compile.

```
#include "mbed.h"

#define BLINKING_RATE     500ms

int main()
{
    int scantimes = 0;
    DigitalIn button1(D4);
    DigitalIn button2(D2);
    DigitalOut ledred(D7);
    DigitalOut ledgreen(D0);
    
    if(button1 || button2 == 1){
        scantimes = 10
        if(button1 == 1){
            ledred == 1
            }
        if(button2 == 1){
            ledgreen == 1
            }
        };
#ifdef LED2
    DigitalOut led(LED2);
#else
    bool led;
#endif

    while (scantimes>=0) {
        led = !led;
        ThisThread::sleep_for(BLINKING_RATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to check your logic here: `if(button1 || button2 == 1)` It does not mean the same as `if(button1 == 1 || button2 == 1)` You might get the desired behaviour through the grace of God, but it depends a lot on what how `DigitalIn` is implemented.

Comment: DigitalIn is implemented correctly. I did also change the OR but get no viable overloaded '='

Comment: @OvercomeSupreme not having an `overloaded '='` is not a reason to use compare operator (that has no effect). Also, are you missing a few `;`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't have "mbed.h" so can't compile, however:

in your code:

```
if(button1 || button2 == 1){
        scantimes = 10
        if(button1 == 1){
            ledred == 1
            }
        if(button2 == 1){
            ledgreen == 1
            }
        };
```

the conditional "==" operator is used in both the condition of the if statement as well as within the body of the statement.

if the goal is to "set" ledgreen or ledred to 1, use "=" instead of "==".  otherwise the program is just checking whether the led's are equal to one, rather than setting their value.

Also, semicolons will be needed at the end of each statement.

Comment: I get the error "no viable overloaded '='"

Comment: [Documentation](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.15/apis/digitalout.html) suggests that `DigitalOut` does have an `operator=` that will accept an `int`.

Comment: DigitalOut::write()
DigitalIn  button(BUTTON1);
DigitalOut led(LED1);
led = button;   // Equivalent to led.write(button.read())

Comment: My point is that `ledred == 1;` will fail, Should compile, but won't do anything. Might produce a compiler watring because no action is taken on the result of the comparison.  `ledred = 1;` should both compile and work. If it doesn't, clean up your code to remove any ambiguities caused by unrelated bad syntax so we can focus on exactly what went wrong and ask a new question. According to the question as written this answer's as correct as you can get with all the extra noise in your code.

Comment: It did work! thanks for all the help!